# Is it possible to use Select Case with nullable values in VB.NET?

Tags: vb.net

The following code

```
Sub Foo(i As Int32?)
    Select Case i
        Case Nothing              ' <-- warning here
            ' Do something
        Case 0
            ' Do something else
        Case Else
            ' Do something different
    End Select
End Sub
```

yields the following warning:

> Warning BC42037: This expression will always evaluate to Nothing (due to null propagation from the equals operator). To check if the value is null consider using 'Is Nothing'.

`Case Is Nothing`, however, yields a syntax error:

> Error BC30239: Relational operator expected.

Is there a way to use `Select Case` with a nullable value type and a case clause for the `Nothing` case?

Comment: Interesting.  `case null` is fine in C#.

Comment: @JamesThorpe: That's probably due to the different default equality implementations. `myObject == null` works in C#, `myObject = Nothing` does not work in VB. `myObject Is Nothing` is required in the latter case.

Comment: Right, that makes sense

Comment: While having a look at this I tried `Case i Is Nothing` which will not be matched for `Foo(Nothing)` but IS matched for `Foo(0)`

Comment: @AFriend: `Case i Is Nothing` does work if you replace `Select Case i` with `Select Case True` and `Case 0` with `Case i = 0`. That's the workaround I currently use, but it gets very repetitive if you have a lot of `Case` clauses.

Comment: An interesting conflict between `Case Is` and `Is Nothing`. It would have been `Case Is Is Nothing`, unfortunately `Is` is not among the [operators allowed after `Case Is`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cy37t14y.aspx). Might be worth a feature request.

Comment: Note that `Case Nothing To Nothing` suppresses the warning and all compiles well, but then it does not match the `Nothing` value.

Answer (score 4):

This is the workaround I currently use. I look forward to other solutions which are less repetitive in the case of multiple `Case` clauses:

```
Select Case True
    Case i Is Nothing
        ' Do something
    Case i = 0
        ' Do something else
    Case Else
        ' Do something different
End Select
```

Comment: This syntax always throws my brain for a loop the first few times I have to read it.

Comment: IMHO, in this situation, `If ... ElseIf ... Else` is simpler. More common, and avoids need for `Select Case True` and `End Select`. Or [Bradley's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/43331066/199364).

Answer (score 3):

I prefer to see the `Select` wrapped in an `If` in this situation. It feels more readable and logical to me, since the lack of a value usually requires a different type of behavior than the presence of a value.

```
Sub Foo(i As Int32?)
    If i.HasValue Then
        Select Case i
            Case 0
                ' Do something else
            Case Else
                ' Do something different
        End Select
    Else
        ' Do something
    End if
End Sub
```

Comment: I was going to suggest `If i.HasValue` as part of `Case Else` code - but in most cases this answer seems more sensible.

Answer (score 2):

Just workaround

```vb
Sub Foo(i As Int32?)
    Dim value = i.GetValueOrDefault(Integer.MinValue)
    Select Case value 
        Case Integer.MinValue ' is Nothing
            ' Do something
        Case 0
            ' Do something else
        Case Else
            ' Do something different
    End Select
End Sub
```

Another workaround can be

```vb
Sub Foo(i As Integer?)
    If i.HasValue = False Then 
        ExecuteIfNoValue()
        Exit Sub
    End If

    Select Case i.Value
        Case 0
            ' Execute if 0
        Case Else
            ' Execute something else
    End Select
End Function
```

In C# 7 `switch` statement already accept other then primitive types, and nullable can be used.
So you can create C# project only for this method and use new features of C# 7 :)

```cs
void Foo(int? i)
{
    switch(i)
    {
        case null:
            // ExecuteIfNoValue();
            break;
        case 0:
            // ExecuteIfZero();
            break;
        default:
            // ExecuteIfDefault();          
    }
}
```

Comment: A valid workaround, but using a magic number kind of defeats the purpose of having a nullable value in the first place.

Comment: @Heinzi - true, that's why i "marked" it as workaround :)

Comment: This doesn't work well if `MinValue` is also a valid value coming in to the `Select`.

Answer (score -3):

I suppose your situation may indeed require it - but do you really need the nullable notation on i ??  You can still pass "Nothing" to i without it.

```
Sub Test()
    Foo(Nothing)
End Sub

Sub Foo(i As Int32)
    Select Case i
       Case Nothing
           'do something
       Case 0
           'do something else
       Case Else
           'do something different
    End Select
End Sub
```

Comment: I'm pretty sure this will not behave the way you expect, as assigning `Nothing` to a value-type will just end up assigning the default value for that type (`0` for `Int32`).

Comment: You are correct - "Case Nothing" and "Case 0" are equivalent, so you cannot get to case 0 with this.

Comment: **M. Ferry and @BradleyUffner:** Note that the OP is suffixing the type with `?`, which is a short-hand for creating [**nullable value types**](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms235245.aspx). So in his case `Case Nothing` and `Case 0` are not the same.

Comment: I'm aware of that, but *this* answer asks if the `nullable` is really required.  I'm saying that "yes, it is", otherwise the code in *this* answer isn't valid.

Comment: I'm aware too - but asked if OP really needed it.  Regardless - my answer really isn't valid because of the reasons @BradleyUffner pointed out.

Comment: Oh, I misread your answer completely. Sorry for that, and any inconvenience. :)